# Java CSV file Manipulation

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I have following sample CSV file

```
rc,u,s,ui,gh
m,1,8,0,12
n,3,0,0,7
d,1,1,8,0
```

I want to read this CSV file and get column by its name (e.g., s). subtract fetched column by some values and update that column in the CSV file.

Is there an easy way to do it in Java?

Comment: if this is homework tell us, please

Comment: This question is pretty broad. One step at a time please. At what step exactly are you stucking while fulfilling the functional requirement? Reading the file?

Comment: It is not homework. I can use OpenCSV to read csv files. I am stuck how to update each column with new values (multiplying or subtracting each column at run time).

Comment: That's Java, right? In future questions please choose one main language tag. If you really need to ask for 2 completely different programming languages, just ask 2 questions (and show the code you have as far so that it's clear where exactly you're stucking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy in PHP, you can use fgetcsv function  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Added Sample

```
    <?php

    $inHandle= fopen("input.csv", "r");

    $text = "";
    $someVar = array(1, 2, 3, 4);           // for subtracting 1 from col1 2 from col2 ...

    while ( ( $data = fgetcsv($inHandle) ) !== FALSE) 
    {
    $text  = $text  . $data[0];

    for ($i= 1; $i < count($data);  $i++) 
    {

        if($i==0)
            $text =  $text .  $data[$i] . ", ";
        else
            $text =  $text .  ( $data[$i] - $someVar[$i -1] ) . " , ";
    }
       $text =  $text . " \n";
    }

    fclose($inHandle);

    $outHandle = fopen('output.csv', 'w');

    fwrite($outHandle , $text );

    fclose($outHandle );
    ?>
```

Comment: Yes, I know about fgetcsv function. But it does not fulfil my requirement (question). Could you please provide sample source code that how to perform such tasks?

Comment: Your example subtract each row, not column.

Comment: Yes, it is subtracting 1 from column 1 and 2 from column2 , so on for each row.

Comment: Sorry, i was unable to edit my comment.

But, first looping over rows then column will not make difference in result.
I have created  $someVar array of four element  You can set create $someVar array of arbitary length for subtracting it from column

Answer (score 0):

```
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path_to_your_file"));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");

       while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
              String token = tokenizer.nextToken(); 
       } 
}
```

This way you can get your comma separated tokens. Do what you want with them and then, have a look at [BufferedWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) class to store back the values.

Comment: What kind of indentation style is this? Or was this blindly copypasted feom Google? Anyway, this does not really answer the question as well..

Comment: @Balusc: here's late. Was just a fast advice to where to look to read a string from file and split it.

Comment: then "subtract fetched column by some values " cannot be done for string values, like the user example..so it's quite difficult to give him a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no 'easy' way of doing this, at least with the standard Java API. Looping is probably going to be the only option here.

There are, however, other languages which make this kind of thing relatively simple. R (freely available and open source) is a great language for data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could try with something like this:

```
<?php
function csv2PhpArray($sFile,$sSeparator = ';'){
$arrCsv;
$arrCsvKeys;
$i = 0;
    if (($handle = fopen($sFile, "r")) !== false) {
        while (($arrRow = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $sSeparator)) !== false) {
            //Each row
            $nLenRow = count($arrRow);
            for ($j=0; $j < $nLenRow; $j++) {
                if($i==0){
                    $arrCsvKeys[] = $arrRow[$j];
                }else{
                    $arrCsv[$arrCsvKeys[$j]][] = $arrRow[$j];
                }
            }
            if($i==0) $i++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $arrCsv;
}
function updateCsv($arrCsv,$sFile,$sSeparator = ';'){
    $arrCsvKeys = array_keys($arrCsv);
    $i = 0;
    $nMaxKeys = count($arrCsvKeys);
    $nMax  = count($arrCsv[$arrCsvKeys['0']]);
    $arrInput;
    for($k=0;$k<$nMaxKeys;$k++){
        $arrInput[$i][$k] = $arrCsvKeys[$k];
    }
    for($j=0;$j<$nMax;$j++){
        $i++;
        for($k=0;$k<$nMaxKeys;$k++){
            $arrInput[$i][$k] = $arrCsv[$arrCsvKeys[$k]][$j];
        }
    }

    $nMax  = count($arrInput);
    $fp = fopen($sFile, 'w');
    for($i=0;$i<$nMax;$i++){
        fputcsv($fp, $arrInput[$i]);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

$arrCsv = csv2PhpArray('file.csv',';');
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arrCsv);
echo '</pre>';
$nMax = count($arrCsv['s']);
for($i=0;$i<$nMax;$i++){
    $arrCsv['s'][$i]= intval($arrCsv['s'][$i])+10;
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arrCsv);
echo '</pre>';
updateCsv($arrCsv,'file2.csv',';');
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(csv2PhpArray('file2.csv',';'));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I put two files (file.csv and file2.csv) to see the update results.

I see you change the answer to only java, but I hope this can be help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JEzCSV](https://github.com/Yiao/JEzCSV) for read or write CSV file, can you can read the code, is open source

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the code I have posted to GitHub which reads CSV, puts the CSV into a POJO, and then writes from the POJO to a CSV file. This modifies the original CSV using the POJO and writes the new columns you need to a new CSV file.

https://github.com/Blue4570/CsvAppender

public class CsvWriter {

```
private File csvFile;
private String delimiter;
static final String NEW_FILE_LOCATION_AND_NAME = "<LOCATION_AND_NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE";


public CsvWriter(String delimiter) {
    this.csvFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("csv/TestCsv.txt").getFile());
    this.delimiter = delimiter;
}

public void writeFile() {
    List<NewTable> tableList = readFile(csvFile);
    try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(NEW_FILE_LOCATION_AND_NAME)) {
        writer.append("ID$FirstName$LastName").append("\n");
        tableList.forEach(table -> {
            try {
                writer.append(table.getId()).append(delimiter);
                writer.append(table.getFirstName()).append(delimiter);
                writer.append(table.getLastName());
                writer.append("\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to write new File");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to write new file");
    }
}

private List<NewTable> readFile(File csvFile) {
    List<NewTable> tableList = new ArrayList<>();
    try (InputStream inputFS = new FileInputStream(csvFile);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS))
    ) {
        // skip the header of the csv
        tableList = br.lines().skip(1).map(mapToItem).collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");
    }
    return tableList;
}

private Function<String, NewTable> mapToItem = (line) -> {
    Optional<NewTable> newTable = Optional.empty();
    if (line != null) {
        String[] p = line.split("\\$");
         newTable = Optional.of(new NewTable(p[0], p[1]));
    }
    return newTable.orElseGet(NewTable::new);
};
```

}